# Count the frequency of a word contained in a string in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

How to count the frequency of a word contained in a string? I have to use XSLT 1.0

Example XML:

```
<a>
   <b>Can you can a can as a canner can can a can?</b>
</a>
```

So the word "can" is presented six times in this string? Can I count can? xD

I used something like this but get only "1"

```
<xsl:value-of select ="count(a/b[contains(.,'can')])" />
```

**Additional Question**: How to count "can" and "Can" but not a "canner" ?

Comment: Well, which XSLT 1 processor do you use? Any support for the EXSLT tokenize function to at least split that string up? Otherwise write a named recursive template that tokenizes the string and counts the substring you are looking for.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">  EXSLT is not supported. Can you give me an example of this template

Comment: If you don't have access to a tokenize function then you could write a recursive template which would cut out the string on the space character and add the number of times is encounters the word you have passed.

Comment: It depends on how you define *word*.  If - as you indicate - "can?" is an occurrence of the word "can", then this is going to be difficult -unless you have a list of all possible punctuation characters that need to be ignored.

Comment: Do you really need to do this with XSLT 1.0? It's getting very long in the tooth and later versions are much more capable.

Comment: Even in XSLT/XPath 3 matching on "words" is difficult with the regular expression support from the specs but Saxon allows you to use the underlying platform like .NET or Java and that e.g. `analyze-string(., '\bcan\b', 'i;n')/fn:match => count()` gives `6`: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jxNakB2

Comment: Of course some XSLT 1.0 processors also allow you to use extension functions with the underlying platform like Java or .NET or Python or PHP where similar regular expressions might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example you could use as your starting point:

**XML**

```
<root>
    <string>Can you can a can as a canner can can a can?</string>
</root>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:variable name="upper-case" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'"/>
<xsl:variable name="lower-case" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'"/>
<xsl:variable name="punctuation" select="'.,:;!?'"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <results>
        <xsl:for-each select="string">
            <count>
                <xsl:call-template name="count-word-occurrences">
                    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="translate(translate(., $upper-case, $lower-case), $punctuation, '')"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="word">can</xsl:with-param>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </count>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </results>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="count-word-occurrences">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="word"/>
    <xsl:param name="delimiter" select="' '"/>
    <xsl:param name="count" select="0"/>
    
    <xsl:variable name="token" select="substring-before(concat($text, $delimiter), $delimiter)" />
    <xsl:variable name="new-count" select="$count + ($token = $word)" />
    
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($text, $delimiter)">
            <!-- recursive call -->
            <xsl:call-template name="count-word-occurrences">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $delimiter)"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="word" select="$word"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="count" select="$new-count"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$new-count"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<results>
  <count>6</count>
</results>
```

---

**Caveats**:

1. The upper to lower case conversion is limited to lower ASCII characters;
2. The list of punctuation characters is incomplete;
3. Beware of punctuation characters that can come *instead* of a space (e.g. a hyphen).